# Angular js bootstrap : CreatePopup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I created a popup in AngularJS & Bootstrap. When I click on the image, I display the popup but with the same image and the same polygon. I want to display each image with its own polygon. I have this HTML code:

Answer (score 0):

try this one [Modal Image](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) my be it will solve your problem.

Comment: my problem is the angular js . i display always the same polygon . and i need to display for each image the polygon associed

Comment: then in model hide background and set border, shadow, padding to image using class. it will create design as you want.

Comment: i didn't get what are you trying to ask, is polygon image's shape or it is deferent element?

Comment: like Image Overlay? see this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp